# Install Meta Tags and Meta Tags Quick modules on the same site

Tags: 7, meta-tags

Short: Are Meta Tag and Meta Tag Quick incompatible modules?

I am configuring a site that has Meta Tag Quick module but it doesn't allow me to have a meta description tag. It creates an Open Graph description meta tag instead.

Then I want to install Meta Tag module but I am afraid of my site crashing or some error. I know I have to do a backup, and I did.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to mention.
Meta Tags Quick does have a meta description field - check the module settings and enable the field for the content types.

Metatags and Meta Tags Quick can be installed on the same site - I've done this successfully (I do suggest testing on a mirror development site first). Bear in mind the two modules will duplicate some fields so you need to decide which fields you want each module to use.

The data cannot be imported from one module to the other however - maybe running SQL commands, but not from Drupal admin